# Custom Shipping Method: need non-instance settings and non-global settings

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want a setting (the title) which applies to all instances and can't be overridden individually.

I also want global settings (available dates) which can't be set per instance.

I hope I'm missing something, but I can't see a way to get either of these things - it seems settings have to be both global and overridable.

Any help will be hugely appreciated.

I have looked at the following but found nothing useful.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Shipping-Method-API-(2.6)

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that my confusion was all down to a bug with a 3rd party plugin, WooCommerce Hide Checkout Shipping Address, and I'll let them know. It replaces the global settings with the instance settings.